# Define a string based on culture info in C# Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to spell word "Colour" as "Color" in US format and as "Colour" in UK format. My applications works in these 2 countries. I need to change the spellings accordingly. I tried it with the following code :

```
string sample = "";

if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-US")
     sample = "Color";
else
     sample = "Colour";
```

But this somehow doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code seems OK, so the problem must be anywhere else

Comment: Side note: I suggest extracting a method/property `IsUS` or alike to avoid *misspelling* pesky errors (`"us-EN"` and alike)

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight the culture defaults to "en-US" regardless of the country you are actually running in.

You need to explicitly set the culture in the view class with the following code:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

after having set the thread culture accordingly:

```
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(GetEnterpriseCultureName(enterpriseCultureId));
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        return ci.Name;
```

You can also override the currency symbol and number separators in this as well.

[Source](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx)

Then, once you've done that the simplest solution is to put your strings into a pair of resource files. One just called "Resource.resx" which is the default and another called "Resource.en-US.resx" (for example) if your default is the UK.

Then .NET will automatically select the correct resources based on the the culture of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to deal with localization and region differences in spelling is to use the [Silverlight Resource Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(VS.95).aspx) that was included into the framework for exactly that sort of thing.

> **The Hierarchical Organization of Resources**
>
> To understand how resources are loaded, it is useful to think of them as organized in a hierarchical manner. A localized application can have resource files at three levels:
>
> - At the top of the hierarchy are the fallback resources for the default culture, for example, English ("en"). These are the only resources that do not have their own file; they are stored in the main assembly.
> - At the second level are the resources for any region-neutral cultures. A region-neutral culture is associated with a language but not a region. For example, French ("fr") is a region-neutral culture.
> - At the bottom of the hierarchy are the resources for any specific cultures. A specific culture is associated with a language and a region. For example, French Canadian ("fr-CA") is a specific culture.